# LUA - How to round a percentage number?

Tags: lua, percentage

I want to round a percentage number like if is 94.5% to show it like that. But if the number is like 10.0% or 100.0% or 40.0% to show only the number 40% without the .0

In JS is Number(percentage).toFixed(1); but idk how it is in LUA.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should `40.0001%` be `40.0%` or `40%` ?

Comment: It should be 40%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first round up to 1 decimal sign, and then use %g to reduce the output of insignificant zeros.

```
local values = {"100.0", "94.25","94.7","20.0"}

for k,v in pairs(values) do
    print( string.format("%g",string.format("%.1f",v)) )  
end
```

out:

```
100
94.3
94.7
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounding a floatingpoint to an integer can be done by `math.ceil()` or `math.floor()`...

```
> for k,v in pairs({"100.0", "94.25","94.7","20.0"}) do print(math.ceil(v)) end
100
95
95
20
> for k,v in pairs({"100.0", "94.25","94.7","20.0"}) do print(math.floor(v)) end
100
94
94
20
```